# search_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

### error

TypeError at /chat/search/
search_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/search/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
search_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'slug'

### my model:

```py
class UserProfile(models.Model)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='face.jpg', upload_to='images/avtar')
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("UserProfile", blank= True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/chat/{}".format(self.slug)
    
    def last_seen(self):
        return cache.get('last_seen_%s' % self.user.username)
    
def post_save_user_model_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        try:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        except:
            pass

post_save.connect(post_save_user_model_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

### My urls:

```py
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',search_view),
url(r'^friend-request/send/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/$', send_friend_request),
url(r'^friend-request/cancel/(?P<id>[\w-]+)/$', cancel_friend_request),
```

### my view:

```py
def search_view(request, slug):

    p = UserProfile.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    u = p.user;print(u)
    sent_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(from_user=p.user)
    rec_friend_requests = FriendRequest.objects.filter(to_user=p.user)
    friends = p.friends.all()
    # is this user our friend
    button_status = 'none'
    if p not in request.user.profile.friends.all():
        button_status = 'not_friend'
    
        # if we have sent him a friend request
        if len(FriendRequest.objects.filter(
            from_user=request.user).filter(to_user=p.user)) == 1:
                button_status = 'friend_request_sent'
    
    if request.method =='POST':
        query = request.POST.get('search')
        results = User.objects.filter(username__contains=query) 
    
    context = {
        'results':results,
        'u': u,
        'button_status': button_status,
        'friends_list': friends,
        'sent_friend_requests': sent_friend_requests,
        'rec_friend_requests': rec_friend_requests
    }

    return render(request, 'chat/search.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

The view function `search_view(request, slug)` is looking for the `slug` argument in the function definition which is not found in the request URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/search/`

So, the request URL should be like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/search/some_slug` not like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/search/`. Add the slug variable to the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable in you url: `url(r'^(?P[\w-]+)/$',search_view)`, you need to use this variable in the Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/search/, but it is not there, that is what this error is telling you